# Issue in executing step definition using ExtendedCucumber from com.github.mkolisnyk library

Tags: java, cucumber

The moment I am adding extended cucumber dependency, the step definition is not executing, when I remove the extended cucumber dependency it works fine and execute step definitions.

Below is the Maven dependency which I am using.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

**/* This part of the code does not execute Step definitions*/**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumber;
import com.github.mkolisnyk.cucumber.runner.ExtendedCucumberOptions;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(ExtendedCucumber.class)
@ExtendedCucumberOptions(jsonReport = "target/cucumber.json",
        overviewReport = true,
        outputFolder = "target")
@CucumberOptions(features = {"./src/test/resources/features"}, plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt",
        "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json", "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml" },
        glue = { "com/test/stepdefinition" },
        monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

**/* This is working fine and executing step defnitions*/**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = { "./src/test/resources/features" }, plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report",
        "json:target/cucumber.json", "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt", "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
        "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml" }, glue = {
                "com/test/stepdefinition" }, monochrome = true)
public class RunCucumberTest {

}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the error when not executing stepdefs?

Comment: Not seeing any error, it's not able to find step definition file and just showing success result. No error.

Comment: Can you try with these settings - `features = {"src/test/resources/features"}` and `glue = {com.test.stepdefinition}`. Any reason you are using such an old version?

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot. I also figured it out and saw your comment. it was old jar. Actually I was refactoring the code from the existing old project and which was having older dependency, just changed the dependencies to 1.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the all cucumber dependency to 1.2.5 then it will work